# Firebase authentication not working (Kotlin in Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm having problems with authentication on Android Studio using Firebase. I've been trying for a week. The code seems to be good, but I can not see the data in Firebase. I've added all the plugins and dependencies.

```kotlin
package com.example.campusversion

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference
import com.example.campusversion.databinding.ActivityRegisterBinding

class RegisterActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth
    private lateinit var databaseReference: DatabaseReference
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityRegisterBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityRegisterBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        binding.btnRegister.setOnClickListener {
            val email = binding.etEmail.text.toString()
            val password = binding.etPass.text.toString()

            if (email.isNotEmpty() && password.isNotEmpty()) {
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                        if (task.isSuccessful) {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            val intent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java)
                            startActivity(intent)
                            finish()
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Login Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                        }
                    }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email and password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        

 

   binding.haveAccount.setOnClickListener {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, RegisterActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide code too for understand your code and problem more.

Comment: "i cannot see the data in firebase" None of the code you shared is accessing the database yet. --- I'd also recommend locally debugging the problem, and telling us the result. If you set a breakpoint on each line of the code you shared, run the code in a debugger, and then check the value of each variable on each line, which is the **first** line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: If you're new to debugging: The Android docs have a great page on [debugging your app](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug) to get you started with, including the section on [working with breakpoints](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#breakPoints) and [inspecting varialbles](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug#variablesAndWatches).

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo didn't solve it yet,  still learning  more about debugging and breakpoints

Comment: Is any of the Toast messages even displayed?

Comment: @AlexMamo only if the input fields are empty

Comment: So is the task successful or not?

Comment: @AlexMamo it should be successful,but I cannot the data in the data in Firebase…now I’m trying to change de code